# Calling class functions dynamically

Tags: javascript, function, class, object

How could I call the class function from its string?

After I check if the function exists

```
if(typeof requestName == 'function') {

 }
```

I need to call the class function, for example `CreateJob` inside class `Foo`. How could I do this?

```
var Foo = function(credentialsObject){
        this.cred = credentialsObject;
    };

    Foo.prototype.SendRequest = function(requestName,dataObj) {
        // If create requestName, job object exists and credentials have been setup, proceed with a requestName call
        if(requestName && dataObj && (this.cred.userID && this.cred.apiKey)) {
            // Check if the function exists
           if(typeof requestName == 'function') {

           }
        }
    };

    Foo.prototype.CreateJob = function(dataObj) {

    };

    Foo.prototype.CancelJob = function(dataObj) {

    };

    Foo.prototype.JobStatus = function(dataObj) {

    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to do that, both to check whether the function exists and to call it

```js
var Foo = function(credentialsObject) {
  this.cred = credentialsObject;
};

Foo.prototype.SendRequest = function(requestName, dataObj) {
  // If create requestName, job object exists and credentials have been setup, proceed with a requestName call
  if (requestName && dataObj && (this.cred.userID && this.cred.apiKey)) {
    // Check if the function exists
    if (typeof this[requestName] == 'function') {
      this[requestName](dataObj)
    }
  }
};

Foo.prototype.CreateJob = function(dataObj) {
  snippet.log('create job')
};

Foo.prototype.CancelJob = function(dataObj) {

};

Foo.prototype.JobStatus = function(dataObj) {

};

var foo = new Foo({
  userID: 'x',
  apiKey: 'y'
});

foo.SendRequest('CreateJob', {})
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Should be as simple as

```
if(typeof this[requestName] == 'function') 
{
   this[requestName] ( dataObj );
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need a reference to `this` before calling the class function ?

Comment: @aashna yes, updated the post. Sorry forgot to add the same. I thought OP is simply asking how call a function dynamically through name.